# File download and reading - xamarin

Tags: android, ios, xamarin

I need to download an xml file for my project crossplatform IOS, Android and Windows phone utilizando xamarin, 
someone have some example of how I can do this and also how to read this file in the phone memory After it is downloaded.

Does each platform have a way to be saved? How do I get my application to save and read correctly?

I have an application on android where I can do the download and read the file, but how do I extend it to other IOS and Windows phone platforms?

Command I use to dowload on Android

```
 using (var client = new WebClient())
                {
                    string url = "http://teste.com.br/hub/feed";
                    client.DownloadStringAsync(new Uri(url));
                    client.DownloadStringCompleted += (s, e) =>
                    {
                        try
                        {
                            string resultado = e.Result;
                            XDocument rss = XDocument.Parse(resultado);
                            var path = System.Environment.GetFolderPath(System.Environment.SpecialFolder.Personal);
                            var filename = System.IO.Path.Combine(path, "rss.xml");
                            rss.Save(filename);
                        }
                        catch
                        {

                        }
                    };
                }
```

Comment: the file I/O should be similar, if not identical, for iOS and Android.  Windows Phone only supports IsolatedStorage.

Answer (score 0):

You are using standard .Net APIs, so whatever works on Xamarin Android will work on iOS. Also it will work on WPF on Windows. But it will not work on the modern Windows (UWP that includes support for Windows 10 Mobile). You need to use `HttpClient` class there instead, possibly some other changes might be needed you'll see errors and you'll have to find the alternative APIs.